# Expanding a Program to calculate a Harmonic Series

Tags: ruby, class, object

so I was given a piece of code about harmonic series and honestly, I just don't know how to approach it. So here it is:

```
class Fraction
attr_accessor :numerator, :denominator


def initialize(n, d)
    @numerator = n
    @denominator = d
end


def +(rhs)
    n = @numerator*rhs.denominator + @denominator*rhs.numerator
    d = @denominator*rhs.denominator

    n, d = reduce(n, d)

    return Fraction.new(n, d)
end


def print
    puts "#{@numerator} / #{@denominator}"
end


def reduce(n, d)
    r = gcd(n, d)
    return n / r, d / r
end


def gcd(a, b)
    if a % b == 0
        return b
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    end
end

private :reduce, :gcd
end
```

The end result should be something like this. If the user enters the number 5:

h1: 1 / 1

h2: 3 / 2

h3: 11 / 6

h4: 25 / 12

h5: 137 / 60

So it also displays all the harmonic steps before it.

Now here's what I struggle with, I have seen from another similar question this line of code:

```
def harmonic_sum(n)
   (1..n).inject(Fraction.new(0,1)) {|r, i| r + Fraction.new(1,i) }
end
```

Is it even possible to solve this problem without this?

If not how would I need to modify it so that it would display all the harmonic steps?

I tried it first without using this piece of code. I first started with asking the user for a number input:

```
print "What harmonic sums do you wish to calculate?"
num = gets.to_f
```

Then I created an object to reference the Class

```
f1 = Fraction.new(?)
```

Well, I am unsure what goes into the parameter. It obviously expects 2 arguments, so if the user writes just a 5, is it Fraction.new(1,num) or Fraction.new(num,1) or something entirely else?

So then, since "reduce" and "gcd" are private, does that mean I mainly have to concern myself with +(rhs)? Will it look something like this:

```
f1.+(?)
```

Apparently, the parameter is going to be a fraction object, but I am honestly a bit confused on how that would look like.

Or maybe my approach to this problem is entirely wrong? Obviously, I don't expect anyone to write a complete code for this, but I would definitely appreciate any advice and helpful pointers. Also, sorry for the wall of text. I tried to be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "What harmonic sums do you wish to calculate?"
num = gets.to_i

f1 = Fraction.new(0,1)
1.upto(num) do |i|
  f1 = f1 + Fraction.new(1,i)
  f1.print
end
```

However, Ruby ships with it's own Fraction class, called Rational. All code could be replaced by:

```
r = Rational(0,1)  # r = 0 is fine too
1.upto(5){|i| p r += Rational(1,i)}
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry that I took so long to response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.tap` inside inject, which is going to send result of `#+` to block as a `x` variable. The result of `#+` is a Fraction, so we can call `#print` on `x` inside the block.

```
def harmonic_sum(n)
   (1..n).inject(Fraction.new(0,1)) do |r, i|
     (r + Fraction.new(1,i)).tap {|x| x.print}
   end
end
```

Try to edit the block, if you want `h1: 1/1`, etc.